# Integrating Whatsapp in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, whatsapp

I'm making a Windows Universal app in which I need to integrate WhatsApp so that I can use all of its features in my app. I tried to use the API for the Windows Forms application but didn't worked out well. So what I want to know is that what are the different ways in which I can use all of the features of the WhatsApp API for WinForms in my UWP app?

P.S.: I have already seen the WhosDown wrapper for Windows 10 but it is a wrapper for WhatsApp Web, not for the WhatsApp application.

Answer (score 2):

> I have already seen the WhosDown wrapper for Windows 10 but it is a wrapper for WhatsApp Web, not for the WhatsApp application.

I guess that you used wrong API, you can refer to the [Windows Phone FAQ Articles](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp), just for example, you can launch `WhatsApp` application and send text from your UWP app like this:

```
string uri = "whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!";
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uri));
```

This solution works only when WhatsApp is already installed on your mobile. If system can not find WhatsApp on your mobile, it will open the Store and show the recommended apps which registered this protocol.

And I just tested, when use this on PC, the store can't find the app in store, seems this app only targets the mobile device, on windows pc, you need to install this app in other way.

Comment: But that's not what i want. I want to do almost everything that can be done from **WhatsApp** in **my app**, without having it in the current device.